# Add friend system failure

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a add-friend system so people can follow each other via their profiles. I havent done the styling yet, it's pure the feature. My problem is as following: the 'Sent invite'button keeps on showing, eventhough the invite has already been sent. Honestly, I cant figure out why. I tested the query in phpmyadmin and it works fine. There's an entry for the 2 users.

**Here are the queries:**

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//SEARCH THE USERNAME OF THE LOGGED IN USER
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM members WHERE user_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($my_username, $my_email);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$username = safe($mysqli,$_GET["username"]);
//LOOK UP THE DETAILS OF THE USERNAME
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, email FROM members WHERE username = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username); 
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($userid, $email);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

//Sent invite <---IT KEEPS SAYING THIS EVENTHOUGH THERE'S AN ACTIVE ENTRY
$friendQuery1 = mysqli_query($myqsli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_one = '$my_username' AND friend_two = '$username' AND invite_sent = 0 ");

//Invite sent, awaiting acceptance
$friendQuery2 = mysqli_query($myqsli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_one = '$my_username' AND friend_two = '$username' AND invite_sent = 1 ");

//Invite accepted. User is friends.
$friendQuery3 = mysqli_query($myqsli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_one = '$my_username' AND friend_two = '$username' AND invite_accepted = 1 ");
```

**This is the html part**

```
<body>
DEBUG:
This is the profile page from <b><?php echo $username ?></b><br />
Emailadres: <b><?php echo $email ?></b><br />
<br />

<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?> 

<?php if  (mysqli_num_rows($friendQuery1) == 0) {
    echo '<div style="width: 150px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #cecece;">Add friend</div>';
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($friendQuery2) == 1) {
    echo '<div style="width: 200px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #cecece;">Invite sent</div>';
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($friendQuery3) == 1) {
    echo '<div style="width: 200px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #cecece;">Already Friends</div>';
}
?>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<b>CURRENT LOGGED IN USER: <?php echo $user_id ?> AKA USERNAME: <?php echo $my_username ?></b>

<?php endif; ?>

Bye.

</body>
```

So basically the 'Add friend' button keeps on showing, eventhough there is an entry where invite_sent is set to '1'. This means it should show the 2nd query aka 'INVITE SENT' button.

I cant figure out whats wrong here :')

**EDIT #1 - SAFE() FUNCTION**

```
function safe($mysqli,$value) { 
   return mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$value); 
}
```

Comment: What does your `safe()` method do?

Comment: Try replacing '==' for '===' in your HTML to catch any failing queries which will return false instead of zero rows.

Comment: Unrelated: if you're using statements (good!), use the correct types. `user_id` seems to be an int, so don't use `'s'`, use `'i'`.

Comment: @Rudie Thank you for the tip! I started using them since yesterday so I'm fairly new to it! Once again, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself. I read every little part of the code and noticed that i used $myqsli instead of $mysqli. Because of this, it didnt show anything.

Comment: Turn on your error reporting! In php.ini, look for `display_errors` and `error_reporting`.